# Problema al introducir codigo php en un echo

Tags: php

Buenas compis tengo un codigo php dentro de una etiqueta echo que NO genera ningun error, pero no muestra el contenido en texto, a ver si podemos entre todos echarle mano al asunto, gracias de antemano.

os dejo por aqui el codigo:

```
    $array_num = count($arrayProductos);
    for ($b = 0; $b < $array_num; ++$b){



    $consultaProducto= mysqli_fetch_array($ResultadoProductos);

        $comprobacionProducto=$consultaProducto['id'];

    if($arrayProductos[$b]== $comprobacionProducto)
            {
                  $arrayProductos[$b];

                 $NombreProducto=$consultaProducto['nombre'];
                 $UnidadesCaja=$consultaProducto['unidadescaja'];

 echo'<div class="cart_items">
    <ul class="cart_items_list">
        <!-- Cart Item -->
        <li class="cart_item item_list d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-start">
            <div class="product d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-start">
                <div><div class="product_image"><img src="images/cart_1.jpg" alt=""> <?php echo($NombreProducto);?> </div></div>
                <div class="product_name"><a href="product.html"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product_color text-lg-center product_text"><?php echo($UnidadesCaja);?></div>
            <div class="product_size text-lg-center product_text">One Size</div>
            <div class="product_price text-lg-center product_text">$19.50</div>
            <div class="product_quantity_container">
                <div class="product_quantity ml-lg-auto mr-lg-auto text-center">
                    <span class="product_text product_num">1</span>
                    <div class="qty_sub qty_button trans_200 text-center"><span>-</span></div>
                    <div class="qty_add qty_button trans_200 text-center"><span>+</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product_total text-lg-center product_text"><span>Total: </span>$19.50</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>';
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No habria necesidad de hacer `<?php echo $NombreProducto; ?>` ni el otro, porque ya estas dentro de un echo solo seria concatenar las variables al echo para imprimirlas.

```
     echo'<div class="cart_items">

                                        <ul class="ca

rt_items_list">

                                        <!-- Cart Item -->
                                        <li class="cart_item item_list d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-start">
                                            <div class="product d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-start">
                                                <div><div class="product_image"><img src="images/cart_1.jpg" alt=""> '.$NombreProducto.'</div></div>
                                                <div class="product_name"><a href="product.html"></a></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product_color text-lg-center product_text">'.$UnidadesCaja.'</div>
                                            <div class="product_size text-lg-center product_text">One Size</div>
                                            <div class="product_price text-lg-center product_text">$19.50</div>
                                            <div class="product_quantity_container">
                                                <div class="product_quantity ml-lg-auto mr-lg-auto text-center">
                                                    <span class="product_text product_num">1</span>
                                                    <div class="qty_sub qty_button trans_200 text-center"><span>-</span></div>
                                                    <div class="qty_add qty_button trans_200 text-center"><span>+</span></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="product_total text-lg-center product_text"><span>Total: </span>$19.50</div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>';
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda amigo!

Answer (score 3):

Hola te recomiendo utilizar la función **echo** de esta manera.

```
echo '<div class="cart_items">
    <ul class="cart_items_list">
        <!-- Cart Item -->
        <li class="cart_item item_list d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-start">
            <div class="product d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column align-items-lg-center align-items-start justify-content-start">
                <div><div class="product_image"><img src="images/cart_1.jpg" alt=""> ' . $NombreProducto . '</div></div>
                <div class="product_name"><a href="product.html"></a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="product_color text-lg-center product_text">' . $UnidadesCaja . '</div>
            <div class="product_size text-lg-center product_text">One Size</div>
            <div class="product_price text-lg-center product_text">$19.50</div>
            <div class="product_quantity_container">
                <div class="product_quantity ml-lg-auto mr-lg-auto text-center">
                    <span class="product_text product_num">1</span>
                    <div class="qty_sub qty_button trans_200 text-center"><span>-</span></div>
                    <div class="qty_add qty_button trans_200 text-center"><span>+</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product_total text-lg-center product_text"><span>Total: </span>$19.50</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>';
```

Concatenando los valores al String.

Answer (score 1):

hola lo que sucede es que esta introduciendo aperturas php dentro del `echo`

ejemplo 1 mal:

```
echo '<?php echo($NombreProducto);?> ';
```

estas diciendo que es texto plano tambien esta metiendo un echo dentro de otro echo y abriendo codigo php dentro de codigo php.

ejemplo 2 mal :

```
echo '<h1>{$NombreProducto}</h1>';
```

si utilizas comillas simple php entendera que lo que viene es solo texto plano por ende no tomara el valor de las variables y solo imprimira tal cual se ve.

ejemplo 3 bien:

```
echo "<h1>{$NombreProducto}</h1>";
// o tambien
echo "<h1>${NombreProducto}</h1>";
// o tambien
echo "<h1>$NombreProducto</h1>";
```

si utilizas comillas dobles el interprente entedera que podria venir varibles que debe remplazar por su valor.

ejemplo 4 bien:

```
echo "<h1>" . $NombreProducto ."</h1>";
// o tambien
echo '<h1>' . $NombreProducto .'</h1>';
```

la sinxatis de punto se utiliza para concatenar strings